# Getting D3 Force to work in Update pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm hoping someone can spot where I'm going wrong here as I've looked at it for over 24 hours and can't see the issue.

I have a fairly complex dataviz working nicely in D3 but the final step is to 'adjust' any overlapping points - primarily so that their individual tooltips are accessible (on hover) (e.g. I don't want to consider alternatives like 'growing' the points to show their combined status).

So, imagine a pinboard where every pin is a point with hit_x and hit_y coordinates. Everything is working perfectly (filtering, updating, etc) in what I understand to be a fairly standard D3 'update' pattern. Sometimes two pins might have the same coordinates.

I thought I'd use D3 forces (for the first time) to recognise the 'colliding' pins and then adjust their positions accordingly. However, whilst I can get a simple version working on [Blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/benchilds/e6a43b3d8317e5f3035749fc0ebe39ac). I can't get the same thing working when applied to my dataviz, even when I simplify it considerably.

I think perhaps I don't 100% understand the simulation process when using from an update pattern. My (simplified) code is pasted below, and here's in effect what I think it should do:

1. Appropriately loaded/formatted data is passed to update()
2. Prepare points ready to attach svg objects (same as 'standard' update pattern).
3. Prepare a simulation (and initially run it via ticked()).
4. Visualise the data.
5. Rerun the simulation so that the collisions are detected...
6. ...during which, ticked() should notice the collisions and adjust the points by adjusting d.x and d.y accordingly until there are no overlaps.

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing - possibly related to whether I should pass the 'points' to the simulation or the original data. If anyone can spot  it then I'd be very grateful. ¯\(ツ)/¯

```
function ticked() {
  console.log("Ticking...");

  points
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}

// Update visualisation
function update(data) {

  // Animation transitions
  var t1 = d3.transition().duration(3000);

  // Add svg group for handling/styling points later
  graph.select("g.points").remove();
  var pointsG = graph.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'points');

  // Data: Points
  // Join new data with old elements
  points = pointsG.selectAll("circle.point")
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d;
    });

  // Forces
  collisionSimulation = d3.forceSimulation(points)
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
    .force('x', d3.forceX(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.point.hit_x);
    }).strength(0.5))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.point.hit_y);
    }).strength(0.5))
    .alphaTarget(1)
    .on('tick', ticked);

  console.log(collisionSimulation);

  // Remove old elements not present in new data
  points.exit()
    .transition(t1)
    .attr('class', 'exit')
    .remove();

  // Append new elements
  points.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'point')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.point.hit_x);
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.point.hit_y);
    })
    .attr('r', 5)
    .merge(points);

  collisionSimulation.nodes(points)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(0.5).radius(function() {
      return 5;
    }));

  collisionSimulation.alpha(0.5).restart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, now resolved - though I would appreciate further input on the `ticked()` implementation.

I imagine someone will go through the same process as me at some point, so following is what I did to get things working. The crux of it is that I had been getting confused joining the forces with the visual objects. By passing the same original data to both, the forces were then able to act on the visual objects, rather than both existing as one.

1. I re-read the core information about [data joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/). I've read this a number of times over the past few months working with D3 but for some reason, reading it again made my forces / update pattern finally make (un)sense in my head.
2. Similarly, despite having used a few excellent Blocks examples for reference, I came across [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@interpolack/d3-4-0-force-layouts-7d814345c796) which made things click for me. It doesn't mean the Blocks examples aren't great - just that for some reason this article helped me.
3. Thereafter, I updated my code and was able to get things working. I feel like I'm still missing a little bit of 'data join' magic in my `ticked()` function though as it seems odd to need to 'search' for the relevant items to act on rather than use a previously built reference. I'm sure I can optimise that, but if anyone else can input then great.

Hope that helps someone else out.

```
function ticked() {

  console.log("Ticking...");

  d3.select('g.points').selectAll('circle.point')
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

}

// Update visualisation
function update(data) {

  // Animation transitions
  var t1 = d3.transition().duration(3000);

  // Add svg groups for organising data elements
  graph.select("g.points").remove();
  var pointsG = graph.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'points');

  // Points

  // Join new data with old elements
  points = pointsG.selectAll("circle.point")
    .data(data, function(d){ return d; });

  // Remove old elements not present in new data
  points.exit()
    .transition(t1)
      .attr('class', 'exit')
      .remove();

  // Append new elements
  points.enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'point')
      .attr('cx', function(d){ return xScale(d.point.hit_x); })
      .attr('cy', function(d){ return yScale(d.point.hit_y); })
      .attr('r', 5)
      .merge(points);

  // Forces
  collisionSimulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .nodes(data)
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(2))
    .force('x', d3.forceX(function(d) { return xScale(d.point.hit_x); }).strength(0.5))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(function(d) { return yScale(d.point.hit_y); }).strength(0.5))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(0.5).radius(function() { return 5; }))
    .on('tick', ticked);

  collisionSimulation.alpha(0.5).restart();

}
```